# How to generate barcode in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, barcode

I want to generate barcode in flutter but I only found barcode scanner packages like [barcode_scan](https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=barcode) but I want something like [zxing](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) library (native in Android) for flutter that also generates Barcode in multiple formats like EAN, Code128 etc. Although my requirement is EAN.

Comment: Which kind of barcode do you want to generate, e.g. PDF 417 symbol?

Comment: I wanted to generate EAN 13 format

Answer (score 6):

I've already implemented a Flutter library did just what you want.

Please check here [barcode_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/barcode_flutter)
EAN8 and EAN13 are both supported.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

[barcode_scan](https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=barcode) uses the [zxing](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) library for the Android plugin, so you could easily extend that plugin to support the APIs for barcode generation. For the iOS version of the plugin, [AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadatamachinereadablecodeobject) is used instead of zxing, since the iOS port of xzing has been discontinued.
Flutter supports iOS 8.0+, and iOS 8.0 introduced APIs for generating barcodes as part of the [Core Image API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage). The supported formats are:

- square QR code
- Aztec code symbol
- PDF 417 symbol
- Data Matrix code symbol

If the barcode you are looking for in this list, it will be easy to fork the barcode_scan package to add the generating functionality for your app.

Comment: Yeah you are right about zxing being used in barcode_scan but I did not find any code for barcode generation in the kotlin class where the library is used which flutter implements. There is only barcode scan() method.

Comment: I also don't know for how to extend barcode_scan plugin to support the APIs for barcode generation. Please show me a way out.

Comment: That's the code you have to implement yourself. Maybe the package owners are interested in adding the functionality. It would make sense, since it's not that much additional code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "SfBarcodeGenerator" in flutter

example

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(`enter code here`
        home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
        child: Container(
            height: 200,
            child: SfBarcodeGenerator(
                value: 'www.syncfusion.com',
                symbology: QRCode(),
            ),
        ))),
    );
}
```